# Uncaught Error: "XL0 L0 M0 S12" is of type string, expected sap.ui.layout.GridSpan for property "span"

Tags: layout, rendering, sapui5

I have a form with multiple input fields, when I add an extra field (I just copy paste the code from one of the above) I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: "XL0 L0 M0 S12" is of type string, expected >sap.ui.layout.GridSpan for property "span" of Element >sap.ui.layout.GridData#__layout10--Dummy

On: ManagedObject-dbg.js:1183 (this is an UI5 javascript file, so I have no control over it)

The code I use in my XML-view is, I use this code for a couple other dropdownboxes.

```
<commons:DropdownBox id="settingRetour_status" items="{statusses>/}" valueStateText="{i18n>RequiredField}" selectedKey="{settingDetail>/value}" displaySecondaryValues="false" searchHelpEnabled="true" visible="false">
                                        <commons:items>
                                            <core:ListItem key="{statusses>code}" text="{statusses>description}" additionalText="{statusses>id}" />
                                        </commons:items>
                                    </commons:DropdownBox>
```

The gridLayout looks like

```
<form:layout>
                    <form:ResponsiveGridLayout labelSpanL="{settings>/ProductDetailFormLabelSpanL}" labelSpanM="{settings>/ProductDetailFormLabelSpanM}"
                        breakpointL="{settings>/ProductDetailFormBreakpointL}" breakpointM="{settings>/ProductDetailFormBreakpointM}"
                        columnsL="{settings>/ProductDetailFormColumnsL}" columnsM="{settings>/ProductDetailFormColumnsM}"/>
                </form:layout>
```

Why do I get this error?

And how can I prevent getting it?

I use openui5-1.42.6 in Eclipse and run it in Chrome

Comment: the xml code you give here is not the good one. Please share your layout declaration :)

Comment: @AshKander I forgot to add a vertical layout inside my grid layout :p problem is now fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the grid layout.

I was adding to many elements to be displayed on one row. There are 12 columns and I added a 13th item, that resulted in an unknown column S12 but because all but one were `visible="false"` I couldn't see this.

After adding a vertical layout to my formcontainer-element the problem was solved.